# Isolating database when run multiple django test suites on Jenkins server

Tags: django, testing, django-models, jenkins, django-postgresql

Our Jenkins test server runs several different test suites for a Django app, and several of these suites require that a Postgres database is present and seeded with data (e.g., integration tests, database migration tests). Currently, we have a single SQL database dump with the test data, and we load that database in for the different tests.

I'd like to be able to run multiple suites concurrently on the same Jenkins server. However, I can't do that with the current model since multiple suites would try to use the same database and clobber each other.

I'll probably just use a sed script to modify the SQL dump file for each test suite before loading it so each suite uses a database with a different name. Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using pg_dump/pg_restore which would let you specify a database to restore into?

Comment: @RichardHuxton We're using django-dbbackup, which uses psql rather than pg_dump/pg_restore.

Comment: Can you pass command-line args to psql using that? If so, you could use `psql -v MYDBNAME=foo` and psql's (slightly fiddly) variable interpolatoin.